I was given a personal tip from another waitress table. Can I legally be fired for accepting the tip?
I was asked to refill drinks, get napkins, and got a to-go box for another waitress' table, and before they left they handed me a tip and said "this is for you."  I accepted it, and then the next day was fired. Is this legal?

Without knowing where you work this is impossible to say. If you work in an at-will state in the US then it is quite possible nothing illegal was done.

Unless they also tipped the waitress whose station that was, you did swipe whatever percentage was her tip. And if the restaurant staff is pooling tips, that means all tips unless they talk to the manager about whether a special exception can be made. 'For you" should be taken as " you' plural in that situation

As mentioned before it is hard to answer the question without knowing where the situation happened. In addition it is hard to proof anything, as I assume that apart from your say and the customers say there is no other evidence. This is good as the benefit of doubt is on your side, however most work contracts can be ended without needing to provide a reason. Insofar it cannot be clearly said, if the dismissal was illegal.

What exactly did they say when they dismissed you?

I strongly disagree with keshlam above. If the customer said "for you" it means "for you", not "for the pool". If the customer specifically says "for you" but you intend to put it in the pool then you should tell the customer and let them make an informed decision, not lie to the customer by pretending to accept the tip but then put it in the pool.

@stef: This may be a matter of variation in local idiom.

If you work in the US in at-will state (both your easy firing and the fact that you were tipped by customers instead of paid a proper wage by your employer hint to that) then yes, you can be fired for "any reason", unless it's protected. "I didn't like the fact you were tipped" seems utterly stupid as a reason, but it would be legal.
That said, most businesses where tipping is a good part of the salary have rules about this. Many for example pool the tips and share them between all workers. If you just pocketed the tip and your company has such a rule, written out, or verbal or maybe only implied, then breaking that rule might be seen very negatively. Basically as theft. Even if there is no such rule, people might have expected you to share the tip with the waitress who also worked that table.
In countries where staff is paid properly and tips are just a bonus, with better labor laws that protect workers, this seems overly harsh. At least talking about it and making you see the mistake, maybe issuing a written warning would be in order. But I guess you live somewhere, where life is a lot harsher than that.
